# How to fix "Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression." in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a form on Access. It is supposed to insert data into a table, but I keep getting error 3464.

I am a little new to Visual Basic. This was previously working, but no longer. I am using SQL Server as a back-end. The connection works and it was inserting new rows. I have looked online but have not found a comprehensive explanation of this error.

```
Private Sub mSubmitButton_Click()

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo_Reporting_Table([Date], Vendor, Ordered_By, Picked_Up_By, Reported_By) " & _
    " VALUES('" & Me.mDate & "','" & Me.mVendor & "','" & Me.mOrdered_By & "','" & _
    Me.mPicked_Up_By & "','" & Me.mReported_By & "')"

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo_Items_Table([PO#], [Item], [Price], [Equipment], [Quantity]) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.mPONumber & ",'" & Me.mItemInput0 & "'," & Me.mPriceInput0 & ",'" & _
    Me.mEquipmentInput0 & "'," & Me.mQuantityInput0 & ")"


    Me.mItemInput0 = ""
    Me.mPriceInput0 = ""
    Me.mEquipmentInput0 = ""
    Me.mQuantityInput0 = ""

    Me.mDate = ""
    Me.mVendor = ""
    Me.mOrdered_By = ""
    Me.mPicked_Up_By = ""
    Me.Requery

    Exit Sub

Error_PopupMessage:
    'Response = MsgBox(Message, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Form Entry Hint", "help", "1000")
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Any advice on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error means that one of the data types in your values does not match the data type of the column where you're trying to insert it. As we have no idea about what the data types are for the columns in your tables, we can't possibly tell you which one is wrong or why. You'll need to look at every column definition to see what type it expects you to provide to it, and then figure out how to properly provide it with that type data in your INSERT statement.

Comment: So what changed? Is [Date] a date/time field? You are using apostrophe delimiters. If this were an Access table the delimiters would be # character. Really should not use punctuation and special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that, in the form, I was not entering all of the required fields before I pressed submit. I now have an if statement that ends the process if the required fields are null. Hope this might be of use to someone.

```
If Eval(IsNull(Me.mDate.Value) Or IsNull(Me.mVendor.Value) Or IsNull(Me.mPicked_Up_By.Value) Or IsNull(Me.mReported_By.Value)) Then
    MsgBox " Make sure you have entered the Date, Vendor, Purchaser, and signed the form. "
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Eval(IsNull(Me.mItemInput0.Value) Or IsNull(Me.mEquipmentInput0.Value) Or IsNull(Me.mPriceInput0.Value)) Then
    MsgBox " Please enter atleast one complete row of an item for the PO. "
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
```